# Should I format my iMac?

Tags: imac, formatting

I have an iMac 27inch from 2009 running El Capitain at work. It was used by other people before I came in working for this company. It seems a bit on the slow side comparing to my home PC. Would formatting it help? (it has a bunch of applications)

Comment: Did you have a look at Activity Monitor to see if some processes are hugging the CPU or using a lot of memory? Is the feeling of "snowless" coming from working inside applications, from accessing the disks or from something else? Right now it could be anything and reinstalling the OS may or may not help.

Comment: I am surprised that you *weren't* given a cleanly formatted system.  I would get someone to help you backup the other users "stuff" then do a clean installation.

Comment: @patrix I'm really new to working with OS. It's only been a week I'm working with this iMac. Where's the Activity Monitor so I could track that? 
Allan it's kind of "run and go" at this company, I'm using windows keyboard with this iMac and an old mouse, both drove me crazy the first few days. Unfortunately I have no saying in this.

Comment: You can launch any application by clicking on the looking glass icon on top right and typing its name ("Activity Monitor" in this case).

Comment: Having a lot of applications will not slow down any computer (Mac or PC) A slow computer is possibly a result of a number of things, available RAM, heavily fragmented HD, lots of things running at startup, lots of (possibly damaged) temporary/cache files. The first thing I would do is run a cleaning tool like (the free) Onyx. Activity monitor will also show you what is running on the Mac (Task Manager) and allow you to decide if it is a cause of your slowness issue. Simply reinstalling the OS fresh may or may not fix the issue. Spend a little time cleaning and troubleshooting first.

Answer (score 1):

If you are new to Mac, the first thing is prepare:

1. Make a Time Machine full backup to a drive over USB locally.
2. See if the Mac boots to recovery - hold Command + R when it starts

Assuming you have both the above, you can wipe and see what a clean Mac looks like. The internet download of the installer is 5 GB or so and the wipe / install should take less than 30 minutes once the download is done.

At that point you can see if you are missing apps and worst case - restore from the backup as if you didn't wipe in the first place - only using time.

You probably don't need to wipe to analyze the performance, but it could help clean up any oddball installations like third party flash / malware / odd browsers and old software you don't need running. A clean start is great to time the things you care about and then see if the system slows down over time.